# How to merge two csv files based on a column value?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge

have two csv files. One with 200 bridges with names of people assigned to them and other data. the second has 800 bridges with the lat/long and other data. I am trying to merge the two csv files in order to get lat/long for the 200 bridges. I am using pandas merge but doesn't matter what "how=" I use it just merges the column headers. if I use "inner" it just adds the 800 bridges to the bottom of the list. examples:

```
import pandas as pd

wb1 = pd.read_csv('br200.csv')
wb2 = pd.read_csv('bridges.csv')


results = pd.merge(wb1,wb2, on='bridge_id', how='left')
results.fillna(value= "N/A", inplace= True)

print(results)

results.to_csv('merger3.csv')
```

[image]

inner merge

Comment: You are doing it right. Could be a problem with the data. Maybe the values on 'bridge_id' have white spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Columns names seems to be mismatching. check

```
display(wb1.columns, wb2.columns)
```

and compare the names
names are in quotes, so whitespaces will show up